# Maximum Recursion in LCS Recursive Function

Tags: python, recursion, lcs

I'm trying to execute an LCS function that utilizes recursion to give me the number of positions the LCS is valid, along with the place of LCS depicted here:

```
input: LCS("smile", "tile")
output: [3, "##ile", "#ile"]
```

Whenever I try and execute it, it tells me that there is a recursion error, as follows:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

What is wrong with my code? I tried to replace the areas where LCS didn't apply through recursion, but where does the function exceed its depth?

```
def LCS(s1, s2):
    if s1 == "" or s2 == "":
        return 0
    else:
        if s1[0] == s2[0]:
            s1 = s1 + s1[0]
            s2 = s2 + s2[0]
            count = 1 + LCS(s1[1:], s2[1:])
        else: 
            s1 = s1 + '#'
            count = max(LCS(s1, s2[1:]), LCS(s1[1:], s2))
    array = [count] + [s1] + [s2]
    print(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first recursive call (`count = 1 + LCS(s1[1:], s2[1:])`), since you just added an element to the end of each of `s1` and `s2`, the sizes of strings being passed are the same as in the call, so you are making no progress towards termination

Inside of `max`, the second recursive call has the same problem: you added an element to `s1`, so the sizes of the string being passed are the same as in the call.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others you are adding a character to your string variable, and chop one off in the next recursive call. This way there will always be recursive calls with a string that has the initial length, leading to infinite recursion.

And with a closer look, this does not make sense:

```
    if s1[0] == s2[0]:
        s1 = s1 + s1[0]
```

Here you add the *first* character to the *end* of the string again. This cannot be right.

Also, the function has the ability to return only 0 (or `None`), but nothing else. This also cannot be right. Whatever the function does, it should always return a value.

As you are interested in the count of matching characters and the `#` filled versions of both original strings, you could let your function return three values (a list) instead of one.

The code could then be made to work like this:

```
def LCS(s1, s2):
    if s1 == "" or s2 == "":
        return 0, '#' * len(s1), '#' * len(s2)
    else:
        if s1[0] == s2[0]:
            count, r1, r2 = LCS(s1[1:], s2[1:])
            return  count+1, s1[0] + r1, s2[0] + r2
        else:
            count1, r11, r12 = LCS(s1, s2[1:])
            count2, r21, r22 = LCS(s1[1:], s2)
            if count2 > count1:
                return count2, '#' + r21, r22
            else:
                return count1, r11, '#' + r12

print (LCS ('smile', 'tile'))
```

Output:

```
(3, '##ile', '#ile')
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Dbix/2).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all clear about your logic: on each iteration, you either move the first character to the end of the string, or you drop it and append a **#**.
The *only* reduction step in this is shortening s2 in the lower branch, but you'll get caught in infinite recursion before you get there.  I added a simple tracing print to the top of the routine:

```
def LCS(s1, s2):
    print("ENTER s1=", s1, "\ts2=", s2)
```

Here's how it gets stuck:

```
ENTER s1= smile     s2= tile
ENTER s1= smile#    s2= ile
ENTER s1= smile##   s2= le
ENTER s1= smile###  s2= e
ENTER s1= smile####     s2= 
ENTER s1= mile####  s2= e
ENTER s1= mile#####     s2= 
ENTER s1= ile#####  s2= e
ENTER s1= ile######     s2= 
ENTER s1= le######  s2= e
ENTER s1= le#######     s2= 
ENTER s1= e#######  s2= e
ENTER s1= #######e  s2= e
ENTER s1= #######e#     s2= 
ENTER s1= ######e#  s2= e
ENTER s1= ######e##     s2= 
ENTER s1= #####e##  s2= e
ENTER s1= #####e###     s2= 
ENTER s1= ####e###  s2= e
ENTER s1= ####e####     s2= 
ENTER s1= ###e####  s2= e
ENTER s1= ###e#####     s2= 
ENTER s1= ##e#####  s2= e
ENTER s1= ##e######     s2= 
ENTER s1= #e######  s2= e
ENTER s1= #e#######     s2= 
ENTER s1= e#######  s2= e
ENTER s1= #######e  s2= e
```

---

When you fail in a run, you need to reset **s2** to its original value.  Your present code backs up with one more character on each string, leaving **s2** permanently bouncing between its last character and NULL.